# Keycloak integration with spring boot not working

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I’m trying to integrate keycloak on a simple spring boot project but it seems like the security-constraints aren’t working. When I make a request it just passes right through and no log is given.

Here is the [Repo with the demo project](https://gitlab.com/wallysoncarvalho/keycloak-springboot-demo).

On this repo, there’s an export `JSON` file of the realm I created to secure this `API`.

I’m using keycloak running on a docker container from an image of version 10.0.2, I downgraded the deps from the project but the error persisted.